# Passing values between classes using getters/setters

Tags: c++, class, pointers, setter, getter

I have 3 classes within a C++/JUCE project: KeyboardGUI, Chord, and Audio.

KeyboardGUI receives an int called rootNote and needs to give this to Chord.

Chord needs to then give this value to Audio.

I am attempting to use getters/setters to achieve this, however I am not sure which way round to use them: i.e.: Do I set chord from keyboard GUI, and set Audio from Chord, OR Do I get from keyboardGUI to chord, and get from chord to audio.

From what I can tell, I need to create 1 instance of Chord in either KeyboardGUI or Audio, and use a pointer to access this instance from the other class, but I cannot figure out how to implement this.

Which way round should I be getting/setting? and where should i use an instance or a pointer?

Function to set from KeyboardGUI to chord

```
            void KeyboardGUI::handleNoteOn (MidiKeyboardState* source, int midiChannel, int midiNoteNumber, float velocity)
            {
            //IS THIS CORRECT?
            chord.setRootNote(midiNoteNumber);
            }
```

Getter/Setter Functions within Chord.CPP

```
            void Chord::setRootNote(int newNote)
            {
                rootNote = newNote;
            }

            int Chord::getRootNote()
            {
                return rootNote;
            };
```

Here I need to access the rootNote and place it in a new variable

```
 void Audio::playChord()
            {

                //get root note from chord - use pointer??;

            }
```

Should I be using a pointer within my Audio class?

Comment: This really depends on what direction you want to flow in. Both should be fine. If `KeyboardGUI` is initiating a change in `Chord::rooteNote`, then it should set it and `Chord` can use it when needed. Similarly, `Audio` can get `Chord::rootNote` when it needs it. Since you have the getter/setter functions set up in `Chord` class, I would use it to `get` with `chord->getRootNote()` from within `Audio::playChord`

Comment: Would it be possible to call Audio::playChord from my Chord class if I implement it this way round?

Comment: Your class needs a reference to any class that it uses. Maybe that reference is an actual object stored within the class on the stack, or maybe it is an object stored on the heap. That choice is up to you as a programmer. Usually the heap is preferred with only a pointer stored in the class, but then you have to explicitly clean up the memory you use. Otherwise you get memory leaks.

Comment: @SteffanDavies Yes you can. Get the pointer to the `Audio` object and call `Audio->playChord`

Comment: You have to figure out what is happening. Is the chord playing the piano, or is the piano playing a chord? Is the tail wagging the dog?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could do it. I am not really sure of the hierarchy of which class would use which, so I just decided Audio is top dog, and it uses the Class Chord at will. Use what is most useful to you.

### Audio.h

```
class Audio 
{
  public:
    Chord * myChordPTR;  //option 1 variable myChordPTR of type pointer to Chord
    Chord myChord;       //option 2 actual chord object stored on the stack

    Audio();
    ~Audio();
    void playChord();
}
```

### Audio.cpp

```
Audio::Audio() 
{
    myChordPTR = new Chord();  //instantiates a Chord object on the heap
}
Audio::~Audio() 
{
    delete myChordTRP;         //frees the memory of the object that was on the heap 
}
void Audio::playChord() 
{
    int rootNode = myChordPTR->getRootNode();
    int otherRootNode = myChord.getRootNode();       
}
```

See how `myChordPTR` is a pointer that allows the `Audio` class to use an object of type `Chord`?

The point here is when a class tries to use another class's methods, it needs some way to refer to a specific object of that class (unless it is only using static methods).

Take note that the arrow operator `->` is used to access members of a pointer, whereas the dot operator `.` is used to access members of the object itself.

I didn't include the `KeyboardGUI` class in an effort to keep this answer minimal, but I think using what I have provided you should be able to figure it out.